# Swift 4 - file system problems about urls(for: in:) and url(for: in: appropriateFor: create:)

Tags: ios, swift, url, filesystems

I am trying to implement audio recording for my app in swift 4. Some tutorials do this when initializing:

```
func getDocumentsDirectory() -> URL {
    let paths = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
    let documentsDirectory = paths[0]
    return documentsDirectory
}
```

I'm new to programming, and even after reading apple docs I still feel confused (BTW, it seems most of the sample codes offered by Apple are written in Objective C, like [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/AVRecorder/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011004)? I'm wondering whether there is an official swift version of it? I just feel hard to understand these objc codes), my questions are:

1, urls(for:in:) asks for a `FileManager.SearchPathDirectory` and a`FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask`. Could I interpret domain mask as the parent directory of a search path directory? The documentation only has a general description of this topic for ios and macOS. I can kind of understand it for macOS because I could open Finder to see the file system, but how can I get the idea what it looks like for ios? What does a ios path looks like and which part corresponds to domain, which part corresponds to search path directory?

2, I've seen many people take `paths[0]` as the returning value but Why is that? The docs say results would be ordered according to domain masks, but here only one domainMask gets passed in, why still taking the first item?

3, another relevant function is `url(for:in:appropriateFor:create:)`, and in the doc there is a description: *The file URL used to determine the location of the returned URL. Only the volume of this parameter is used.* What does the "volume" mean here?

I know these question may be silly, but I just feel the documentation is limited for me to understand these concepts. Some other tutorials are either over-simplified or out of date. Any advice about this? Thank you in advance!

Comment: In iOS There are just a few options for you  for the search path `.documentDirectory` or `.libraryDirectory`. For the domain you will only need the `.userDomainMask`. About the zero index that’s because urls return an array with a single element but better to use array .first property to get the first (single) element